# Why Can't Generics Be Used to TypeCast

Tags: generics, types, mismatch

Quick question on Generics; I'm understanding that the Generics are pointers in but I'm attempting to print out data; however I am getting a "type mismatch, cannot convert from String Test. This brings a question on how things are actually stored if you cannot use data even if it is parameterized.

```
public class TestProgram {

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        
        
        
        Test<String> hello = new Test<String>();
        String floob;
        
        floob = "hello";
        hello.data = floob;
        
        
        
        System.out.println(hello.data);
        
                
        
    }
        
}
```

This is my Test class code:

```
public class Test<E> {

    Test link;
    Test data;
    
        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Test class, you have defined link and data as raw types instead of using the generic type parameter E. This means, that link and data can hold any type of object. And, not just the type E, which is what you intended for generics.

Use generic type parameter E in your Test class as:

```
public class Test<E> {
    Test<E> link;
    E data;
}
```

Comment: So declaring a class with <E> means I will need to declare the objects as <E> as well or it will be considered a raw type? What is the general use for raw types in programming; I know the we genenrally use them for classes but does defining a class as a generic type without delcaring it as an Element have any use cases? And would I need to still use that 'E data' type or could I do 'Test data' and it be legal?